# Permanent redirecting to different domain via .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I got two domains. Lets say `dom.com` and `dom.net`.

Now I got alias on `dom.net` to `dom.com`, so when I come to `dom.net` it shows me `dom.com` - this is set on admin's webpage.

But I need when somebody comes from `dom.net` redirect him to `dom.com/test/example.html`.

My `.htacces` file is blank now.

Is it possible to do this using `.htacces` and how can it be done?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Using the Redirect option. e.g. Redirect "/foo.html" "/bar.html". Anyway, your question should be more self explained.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dom.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dom.com/test$1 [R=301,L]
```

this code redirect me to `test` folder but still don't know how to redirect to .html page

Comment: replace the last line with these lines RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dom.com/test/$1 [R=301,L]